# Handling data rendering on redux state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to setup a form. It has Edit feature where on edit I call an API and get the data into state.
I'm struggling to display data in the form after api call. There's no problem utilizing the API or calling the redux functions. Problem is that my Form only displays last data in the redux state but not the updated data.

That's how I'm doing the stuff.

1. Calling API if `isEdit===True` at the same time Form is being displayed on component mount.
2. Updateding state after success as an object called `customer`
3. accessing the customer object like this

   const { customer } = useSelector((state) => state.customers)

Lets say I have a input field where I want to display the email of customer.

I'm handling this think like that:

```
email: isEdit ? customer?.email : '', // At this point there is some problem
```

It loads the previous data that was stored in the `state.customer` but not the new one.
I believe my email field is rendering first and then doesn't updated the value when change happens in `state.customer`.

So how I can fix this? So that email value should be changed at the same time if state.customer got changed

Here is the full component. Still removed irrelevant part.

```
const CustomerNewEditForm = ({ isEdit, id, currentUser}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  console.log('isEdit', isEdit, 'id', id, 'currentUser', currentUser)
  // get sales reps
  
  const { customer } = useSelector((state) => state.customers)
  // const customer = () => {
  //   return isEdit ? useSelector((state) => state.customers?.customer) : null
  // }

 
  

  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()

const defaultValues = useMemo(
    () => ({
      email: isEdit ? customer?.email : '',
      name: isEdit ? customer?.name : '',
    }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [currentUser]
  )

  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(NewUserSchema),
    defaultValues
  })

  const {
    reset,
    watch,
    control,
    setValue,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { isSubmitting }
  } = methods

  const values = watch()


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEdit === true) {
      dispatch(getCustomerDetails(id))
      console.log(customer)
    }
    
    if (isEdit && currentUser) {
      reset(defaultValues)
    }
    if (!isEdit) {
      reset(defaultValues)
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isEdit, currentUser])

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500))
      reset()
      let body = {
        email: values.email,
        name: values.name,
        
      }
      console.log(body)
      dispatch(createCustomer(body))
      enqueueSnackbar(!isEdit ? 'Create success!' : 'Update success!')
      // navigate(PATH_DASHBOARD.admin.root)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <FormProvider methods={methods} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
     
      
     
              <Grid item md={3}>
                {' '}
                <RHFTextField name="name" label="Customer Name" />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item md={3}>
                {' '}
                <RHFTextField name="email" label="Email Address" />
              </Grid>
        
    </FormProvider>
  )
}

export default CustomerNewEditForm
```

Here in the component `defaultValues` carries the previous data from customer object if its True and renders the form with those values. but new data comes a miliseconds later but form renders first.

Comment: Please don't share a single line but the full component. You could be doing all kinds of wrong things and nobody can point it out to you like this.

Comment: @phry please check the updated question. Ihv included the component code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to console.log your customer data and make sure that it gets a fresh data on last render.

If it gets fresh data, try take a look at your Input component, it might set some initial data, so the input will be editable and controlled by some state.

Try to modify your input's state on redux store update in useEffect.

Currently that's all that I can suggest, update your post with code with your form and input, also post your console.log result, if my answer doesn't helped you.

If the problem would be not in form\input state and console.log wouldn't show you actual updated data in last render, then I will need to see your redux store code to resolve this issue.

Hope it helped

Comment: Hey Please check the udpated questions. I hv added the more details.

Comment: const `defaultValues ` contains the values if either coming from redux or overridden after.